# Can not replace classic messagebox with CTaskDialog in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc, messagebox, taskdialog

I have a mfc application where classic looking messagebox are used all over. I want to replace them with CTaskDialog. first I added afxtaskdialog.h but got error of _UNICODE not defined . When I put #define _UNICODE in the header file of the .cpp , some errors about unresolved externals are showing up. What am I missing or doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't define _UNICODE in the header files.

Please set the project settings **General -> Character Set -> Use Unicode character Set**!